# Using tee, I lose my sudo privileges

Tags: logging, sudo, tee

I am writing an installer script and need to run it a `sudo` as I test it on AWS RedHat instances, so  can't directly go as `root`. I want to write the log into a file as well as onto the screen. Nothing should be easier than that,

I can either go old school `>> /tmp/Solr_Install.log 2>&1` and start a tail process in the background: `tail -f installer.log &` This solution tends to duplicate or triple the output on the screen, so I opted for a tee-totaller solution.

Just use the power of the force and `2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/Solr_Install.log` With this solution, I lose my sudo rights, and the script fails.

Questions:
Why does the tail show the same line 2-3 times? (Has it got something to do with the fact that `tail -f` displays the last 10 lines?)

- Can this be fixed somehow?
- Why do I lose my sudo when I tee?
- Can this be avoided?
- Is there any other way to throw log materials into a file and onto the screen at the same time?

Comment: Maybe this could be the case that fits your needs http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/redirect-all-subsequent-commands-stderr-using-exec

Comment: Echoes_86, I need to beg for your forgiveness. I doublechecked and your solution, well technically, @BatchyX solution works. I still don't know why I lose my sudo mojo, but hey, at least I have a working solution.

Comment: I'm happy you found your solution. For me, the approach (as I understand from your question) of `exec > >(tee "/tmp/Solr_Install.log") 2>&1` is the best for you.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is not a privilege specific to the session.  `sudo` is a command that runs other commands with elevated privileges.  So just run your `tee` with `sudo`:

```
2>&1 | sudo tee -a /tmp/Solr_Install.log W
```

Comment: It is not the tee that does not work, it is the rest of the script that fail because of tee. Please do not upvote this answer as is, no offence, because it is not an satisfactory answer.